# Cause(s) for WKInterfaceController openParentApplication to fail to send

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

Reading through the Apple docs I see that `[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error))reply]` returns a `BOOL`.

The docs further state:

> Return Value
>   YES if the request was sent successfully or NO if the request was not sent.

My question:

What would cause this function to return `NO`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `NO` may be returned if, for example, the connection between the watch and the phone suddenly got lost.

(Soon after the connection loss, the WatchKit extension will no longer work at all anymore since it requires a connection to the iPhone.)